# report on price list options?

Tags: civievent, participants

I'd like to create a report that summarizes the number of registrations for each price set selection. 
I'd like to quickly show how many people registered at each price level. I know I can create a report of all the people who chose a price option and then get the number at the bottom. However, I have many options and would like a nice summary similar to this:

- A1: 27
- A2: 12
- B1: 17
- B2: 2
- ...

This seems like a reasonable thing to do, but I don't see any way to do it. Possible? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give our Extended Report extension a go since it offers Price Set Line Item reporting options

https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport

Comment: Thank you. That is pretty close.

Comment: are you Keith using a different account?

Comment: I didn't think I had another account, but I guess so, yes.